# Magento 2| How to add "Add to cart" Button functionality in jQuery?

Tags: magento2, javascript, addtocart, jquery

I am adding "Add to cart" button functionality in jQuery function for calculated product quantity. I have add simple button yet. I have doing it as:

[image]

My function is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#inputalgolia").keyup(function(){
        $("input").css("background-color", "grey");
        index.search(this.value, function(err, content) {
            // console.log(content.hits);
            var dataobj = content.hits;
            var product=''; 
            $.each(dataobj, function () {
                product+='<div style="width:500px;height:200px;border:2px solid red;margin-bottom: 20px;">'+
                '<p>' + this.name  +'</p>'+
                '<p>' + this.sku  +'</p>'+
                '<p>'+this.image_url  +'</p>'+
                //'<p>'+ this.objectID  +'</p>'+
                '<input id="algolia-qty-' + this.objectID + '" data-product="' + this.objectID + '" class="qty-triggered" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">'+
                '<button type="button">Add to Cart</button><br>'+
                '<input id="algolia-sqm-' + this.objectID + '" data-product="' + this.objectID + '" class="sqm-triggered" type="number">'+ '<input id="algolia-width-' + this.objectID + '" data-product="' + this.objectID + '" value="150" type="hidden">' + '<input id="algolia-height-' + this.objectID + '" data-product="' + this.objectID + '" value="400" type="hidden">' + 
                '</div>';
                $('#productsalgolia').html(product);
            }); 
        });
    });
});
```

Can anybody explain how to do it, Thanks.

Comment: You want to perform "Add to cart" in admin?

Comment: Yes, when admin creates order he will have this functionality.

Comment: I don't think you need to do it by yourself. Magento 2 backend can create order. You can add product into cart by click **Add products** or **Add products by SKU** in section **Items Ordered**

Comment: Yes it is, but I am doing it for extended features. Need to add products from algoilia search that are coming up in popup.